# Display Multiple div column in alternate format

Tags: css

I am using for each Loop to display div content .

```
@foreach($data as $value)
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    content-1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    content-2
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
       Content Three
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    content4
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I am Trying to Display div in alternate format,
For Example.
#div4 should be on div three position and #div3 on #div4 position .

Comment: You mention `#div4`, but there's no div with an id like that. Also for foreach, it'll output all these divs for every value. + What framework is this? Add a tag or an explanation.

Comment: HenrijsS@ #div4 is example .I divided row in two column and foreach loop   printing column according value. This is Laravel Framework .